# Band unit change from mol/m^2 to micromol/m^2 in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am working on NO2 data of Sentinel 5p in GEE(Google Earth Engine) the unit of band "NO2_column_number_density" is  mol/m^2.

Will someone guide me how can I change the unit from  mol/m^2 to micro mol/m^2?

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_NO2')
  .select('NO2_column_number_density')
  .filterDate('2019-06-01', '2019-06-06');

var band_viz = {
  min: 0,
  max: 0.0002,
  palette: ['black', 'blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
};

Map.addLayer(collection.mean(), band_viz, 'S5P N02');
Map.setCenter(65.27, 24.11, 4);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply multiply your resulting image with the conversion factor:

```
collection.mean().multiply(1e6)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/88c459daf246629c339f537773357e33

Comment: Thanks, mate. It works fine. I am new to GEE and learning.