# GEE Air pollution SO2

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am new to using Google Earth Engine.
I'm trying to extract the SO2 values in my workspace. I just want to show my workspace but I can't.

My code is as below:

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_SO2')
  .select('SO2_column_number_density')
  .filterDate('2019-05-01', '2019-05-31');

var band_viz = {
  max: 0.0004,
  min: 0,
  palette: ['black', 'blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
};

Map.addLayer(collection.mean(), band_viz, 'S5P SO2');
Map.setCenter(30.4, 32.6, 6);

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: collection.select('SO2_column_number_density').mean(),
  description: 'SO2_15-3-2019',
  scale: 50,
  region: geometry,
  fileFormat: 'GEOTIFF',
  folder: 'GEE',
  fileNamePrefix: 'SO2_15-3-2019',
  maxPixels: 5000000000
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To export it you must define a var geometry:

```
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: collection.select('SO2_column_number_density').mean(),
  description: 'SO2_15-3-2019',
  scale: 50,
  **region: geometry,**
  fileFormat: 'GEOTIFF',
  folder: 'GEE',
  fileNamePrefix: 'SO2_15-3-2019',
  maxPixels: 5000000000
});
```

[image]
Draw a shape or import it from your assets and call it "geometry"

Comment: Thank you so much Daniele. One more question, All of the values I get are between 0 and 1.When I look at other studies, I always see high values. Do I need to convert?

Comment: Maybe you must convert it in micromol https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/397846/band-unit-change-from-mol-m2-to-micromol-m2-in-gee

Comment: thank you so much Daniele. Last question :) How can I get the time series (chart) ?